# extract values from an object with forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, foreach

I run a graphql query and obtain data (data.personalPlaces), an object that looks like this:

```
nodes: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

where each node is like this:

```
0:
customisedName: "HomeOfBestFriendAlice"
id: 1
placeName: "Husbrok 1, 26127 Oldenburg, Deutschland"
center: "Zes"
__typename: "FavouritePlace"
__proto__: Object
```

I want to iterate through all nodes such that I can make an array out of it

```
  favouriteLocations: [
    {
      name: 'Zu Hause',
      street: 'Müllersweg',

    },
    {
      name: 'Büro',
      street: 'Philipp-Reis-Gang',
    },
    {
      name: 'KaffeeHaus',
      street: 'Cloppenburgerstr.',
    },
  ],
```

where name is the customisedName and street is the placeName from my original data. How can I achieve this?

Data shape:

```
{
  "data": {
    "personalFavouritePlaces": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "placeName": "Paris, France"
        },

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.map() on the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const favoriteLocations = data.personalFavouritePlaces.nodes.map(node => {
  return {
    name: node.customisedName,
    street: node.placeName
  }
}
```